# Polymorphous Rush targeting Young Pyromancer and X Tokens

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Polymorphous Rush](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polymorphous%20Rush) targeting X tokens, turning them all into copies of a [Young Pyromancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Young%20Pyromancer), do I get an elemental token from each copy, similar to Scapeshift with Valakut on the battlefield?

Comment: @doppelgreener The information in the title is all the OP provided; I filled in the rest, figuring it was about trying to put together a combo deck. But... even if it's your opponent's Pyromancer, the spell is still cast before the tokens become copies, which is I think what the OP was trying to figure out. I don't think there was confusion about whether your spells trigger your opponent's Pyromancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Young Pyromancer's trigger happens when you first cast a spell, which in this case is before Polymorphous Rush will resolve and create more copies. At the time that Polymorphous Rush was cast, there was only 1 Young Pyromancer around, so that it the only trigger that there is.

The stack would look like this:

A: (Cast Polymorphous Rush)

```
Stack:
-Polymorphous Rush
```

B: (Young Pyromancer triggers from spell being cast)

```
Stack:
-Young Pyromancer's triggered ability
-Polymorphous Rush
```

C: (Players pass priority; Young Pyromancer's triggered ability resolves; red elemental token enters battlefield)

```
Stack:
-Polymorphous Rush
```

D: (Players pass priority; Polymorphous Rush resolves; targeted creatures become copy of Young Pyromancer):

```
Stack:
-(Empty)
```

As you see, when the other Pyromancers are all created, there is no spell being cast at that point; Polymorphous Rush was already cast. You would need to cast another spell after this in order to trigger all the new Young Pyromancers.

Comment: Thanks for this. As an addendum, if I have a Purphoros, God of the Forge

Comment: @user3730788 You forgot to actually ask a question, but the answer is nothing happens. Purphoros triggers when creatures enter the battlefield, and nothing is entering the battlefield here. Creatures already on the battlefield are turning into other things, but they were all already there.

Answer (score 2):

Young Pyromancer triggers when you *cast* a spell. Polymorphous Rush is just one spell, no matter how many targets you give it, so it triggers your Pyromancer just once. Once it resolves, you'll have plenty of Pyromancers around, so if you cast *another* spell you can trigger all of them.

Remember, you cast a spell, it goes on the stack, and *then* it resolves. (After anything else that happened in response, of course.) Young Pyromancer triggers when it's cast, and the tokens are turned into copies when it resolves.